# uib-typeahead dropdown doesn't disappear when focus shifts?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I've got a dropdown in this spreadsheet-like UI which provides a list of names as possible valid entries for the cell.  When I tab or return out of the cell, it disappears as it should, but when I click away, to a different cell, the dropdown list isn't dismissed.  Any thoughts on how to get that to work?  (Theres a lot going on in the code, including ng-keydown and ng-blur directives, too involved to show here, but any pointers what to look for would be appreciated.)

Here are some pictures:

[image]
Works properly as I start typing -- but when I click to another cell:

[image]

Drop down still remains...

Comment: are you using angular js?

Comment: yes, angularjs plus angular-ui bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, there was an 'event.preventDefault' in the blur event in certain circumstances which is responsible for the  box not dismissing.